# Condition for a plane curve to intersect its osculating circle

Tags: differential-geometry, curves, plane-curves, frenet-frame

> The osculating circle of a curve $\alpha$ at the point $p \in \alpha$ is the circle $\mathbb{S}^1$ which is tangent to $\alpha$ at $p$ and has radius $\frac{1}{k(p)}$. Show that, if $k'(p) \neq 0$, then the osculating circle at $p$ intersects $\alpha$.

I'm trying to do this by using the canonical forms at $p$ of both $\alpha$ and the osculating circle. Obviously I know the canonical form of $\alpha$, but I'm having a hard time computing the canonical form of the osculating circle, even though I know it's equation is:

$$S = c(t) + \frac{1}{k(t)}(\cos(t),\sin(t)) =\alpha(t) +\frac{1}{k(t)} N(t)+ \frac{1}{k(t)}(\cos(t),\sin(t)) \\= \alpha(t)+\frac{1}{k(t)}(N(t)+(\cos(t),\sin(t)))$$

Comment: You mean intersects $\alpha$ at some point other than $p$?

Comment: @TedShifrin I am. I mean, otherwise the exercise wouldn't even make sense (the osculating circle intersects $p$ at $\alpha$ by definition). The hint given is "use the canonical form of $\mathbb{S}$ and $\alpha$ and compare the coordinates at a neighboorhood of p", but I'm having some trouble doing so.

Comment: In the canonical form you're using $T$ and $N$ at $p$ to give your coordinate axes. You haven't yet done so.

Comment: @TedShifrin Well, my work was setting $p = t_0$ and assuming that $\alpha(p) = (0,0)$, $T(p) = (1,0)$ and $N(p) = (0, 1)$, then:

$$S_{t_0} = \frac{(\cos(t), \sin(t) + 1)}{k(t_0)}$$ and

$$\alpha(t) = (t - t_0)T(t_0) + \frac{(t-t_0)^2}{2} k(t_0) N(t_0) + \frac{(t - t_0)^3}{3}(k'(t_0)N(t_0) - k^2(t_0) T(t_0))$$

I don't see how this is related to the conclusion asked in the exercise, though.

Comment: My goal was to set both expressions equal to each other, find the intersection point and see that it was in a form that only made sense if $k'(t_0) \neq 0$, but that led me nowhere.

Comment: First, you shouldn't use the same parameter for the two curves. I'm also fine with assuming $t_0=0$. Collect terms and write the expression for $\alpha(t)$ *also* in ordered pair notation. [Note: You need $3!$, not $3$, in the denominator.] Maybe it would be better to use a cartesian equation for the circle and see when $\alpha(t)$ solves that cartesian equation?

Comment: @TedShifrin Thanks for pointing out my mistakes. I get:

$$\alpha(t) = \left(t - k^2(0) \frac{t^3}{6}, k(0)\frac{t^2}{2} + k'(0) \frac{t^3}{6} \right)$$

And for the circle:

$$x^2 + \left( y-\frac{1}{k(0)} \right)^2 = \frac{1}{k(0)^2}$$

but checking whether or not $\alpha$ solves the cartesian equation gives me a rather nasty expression that doesn't make the problem any clearer (or, if it does, I'm not seeing it). Is there a better approach or did I miss something?

Comment: This is right. But work out the algebra for the leading powers (quadratic and cubic) and see what happens. BTW, an easier version of this phenomenon appears in my exercise 1.2.13.

Comment: @TedShifrin Working out the algebra I get a polynomial that has leading powers of $6$. Am I taking the best approach in just expanding everything out or is there a smarter way? I saw your exercise too, if I'm not mistaken there was even a solution to it on the proof of a proposition in another book I'm using.

Comment: No. You've messed up. The quadratic terms should cancel and you should be left with a cubic term with coefficient some multiple of $k'(0)$.

Comment: @TedShifrin I just used [Wolfram](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(t+-+(k(0))%5E2+t%5E3%2F6)%5E2+%2B+(k(0)t%5E2%2F2+%2B+k%27(0)t%5E3%2F6+-+1%2Fk(0))%5E2) to check my work and it seems to agree with me that there's a term to the $6$th power. So it would appear I'm not even checking it correctly. Can you point out where I messed up?

Comment: Of course there are *higher* order terms. You're looking for *lowest* order (that's what "leading" means in this context) ... Remember that these are really infinite series, after all ...

Comment: Thanks for clearing up my misconceptions (I didn't realize the fact that I could just "throw out" all the terms raised to a power greater than $3$). So doing that, I get that if $k'(0) \neq 0$, then $t = 0$ is a solution, as asked in the exercise. Did I do everything right and can say the problem is done now?

Comment: No, you want a nonzero solution! (Now we're back to my original comment. You want a point *other* than $p$.) Don't throw away everything after degree 3! :)

Comment: @TedShifrin the lowest degree in the expression is $3$, and since I can't throw away everything after degree $3$, what, if anything, *can* I throw away? I don't know how to solve a sixth order polynomial and I don't think the exercise will get me in that position, so what am I missing here?

Comment: You have an equation of the form $at^3 + bt^4 + ct^5 + o(t^5)= 0$, with $a=-k'(0)/3\ne 0$ and $b=(-k(0)^2/12+k(0)k'(0)/8)$. If $b=0$, consider $c$. Regardless, you will have a nonzero solution for $t$ small.

Comment: Before I consider all of that, are you sure that's right? I'm getting: $$\left(t - (k(0))^2 \frac{t^3}{6}\right)^2 + \left(k(0)\frac{t^2}{2} + k'(0)\frac{t^3}{6} - \frac{1}{k(0} \right)^2 =  \frac{1}{36} t^6 k'(0)^2 + \frac{1}{6} k(0) t^5 k'(0) - \frac{t^3 k'(0)}{3 k(0)}+ \frac{1}{36} k(0)^4 t^6 - \frac{1}{12} k(0)^2 t^4 + \frac{1}{k(0)}^2$$

Comment: If we're going as far as the $t^4$ term, we need to include the $t^4$ term in $y(t)$ [since it appears linearly]. The $t^4$ term in $x(t)$ will not show up until much higher powers ...

Comment: @TedShifrin I don't follow. Isn't the only coefficient of $t^4$ equal to $-k(0)^2 / 12$?

Comment: Did you continue the Taylor series for $\alpha$ to order $4$? I think I screwed up, but you need the $t^4$ coefficient of $N(0)$. So you should be getting something like $1/4!(k''(0)-k(0)^3)$ or some such. This exercise becomes too technical to be worthwhile, even though the geometry is clear.

Comment: @TedShifrin, I only continued it up to order $3$. The only thing messing up the waters here is highschool algebra, right? Asking just to make sure this wall I'm trying to crack to get to the desired result can be cracked with just that. Also, up to what order *should* I expand the Taylor series and why particularly that order? Anyhow, thanks a lot for your patience, you've been extremely helpful. I appreciate that a lot.

Comment: You expand as far as you have to to prove the result. Here we *have* to go to at least the $t^4$ terms to get a nontrivial equation to solve. You should move on to surfaces. Enough of this! :)

Comment: @TedShifrin Thanks! I almost get it now. One last question, though: when I expand at least to the $t^4$ term, is it legal to throw away every higher order term?

Comment: @Ted Shifrin About that last part: I had moved on to surfaces (got as far as only sort of understanding the gaussian curvature) just as soon as my vacations from university ended. Now that classes are back, just a few days ago I managed to speak to an excellent professor whom I expect to be my advisor for a program of undergraduate research in differential geometry (which I'm extremely happy for), and this exercise was in a chapter he recommended me from another book, and so I decided to take the burden of finishing (almost - some are too trivial) every exercise in the chapter (including this)

Comment: But I will move on to surfaces soon enough (with yours and others' books to guide me as well, thankfully!). :)

Comment: Congrats on the adviser. I know you're very excited.